# Can I remove a grid-template-column using mixins?

Tags: css, sass, grid, css-grid, mixins

I'm making a breakpoint (360x640) on my page, and I want to remove one column from my grid template and add one row. I have 3 columns and 3 rows - I wanna have 2 columns and 4 rows.
I added mixin which should do the work but it only added row, doesn't remove column. Can you see where is the problem? Is it possible in general, to remove stuff using mixins?

My html

```html
<div class='c-counter'>

    <div class='count-column c1'>
            <img src="./images/office-block.png" alt='biurowiec'>
            <h3><span class="counter">135</h3>
                <p>lokalizacji w Polsce</p>
    </div>

    <div class='count-column c2'>
        <img src="./images/customer.png" alt='zadowolony klient'>
            <h3><span class="counter">96778</h3>
                <p>zadowolonych klientów</p>
    </div>

    <div class='count-column c3'>
            <img src="./images/work-team.png" alt='partnerzy biznesowi'>
            <h3><span class="counter">26</h3>
                <p>partnerów biznesowych</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

And scss

```css
.c-counter {
  @extend %gradient;
  @extend %shadow-component;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 6fr 1fr;
  .count-column {
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    text-align: center;
    color: $bisque;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 6fr 6fr 1fr;
    .count-column {
      grid-row-start: 1;

      & + .c3 {
        grid-row-start: 3;
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 2;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my knowledge you can override style with **@mixin** but no remove it completly, to get close to it you can set style to *unset*, but i dont think so it is what you need here.

try adding this to your count-column class it should match number of columns and rows to size of the window.

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
```

You can read about it here:
https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/